# Adding a clickable link to a Generic Inquiry in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

We have an application outside of Acumatica that has a page that accepts an order number in the URL. I want to create an Acumatica report that has a row for each filtered order and a column with a clickable link that will open this external dashboard in a new window, passing the order number in the URL.

I've gotten as far as creating a column in the Results Grid with a formula:

=Concat( 'DASHBOARD_URL', [SOOrder.OrderNbr])

How could I make this field into a clickable link? Or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: In 2018R2 version that option has been added

Answer (score 0):

You can create a report instead of Generic Inquiry. In report you can create parameters to filter your records and use Navigate properties for any field value where you want the link.

I don't think in Generic Inquiry you can set a link to external URL. Haven't explored 2018R2 yet.